# How to solve this strong dependency between those classes?

Tags: oop, kotlin, design-patterns

I have two classes `A` and `B`.

Class `A` has several properties. One of them are an instance of class B.

At some point in the `main` function I will define an instance `a` of `A`. I will need to do some computation on its property of type `B`.
This computation, however, needs another property of `a`.

The result is `a.property3.computation(a.property1,someValue)`. I think it's ugly.

Here is some "pseudo-code" (in Kotlin but I am facing the same problem using other languages as well):

```kotlin
class B {
    val property : Map<String,Int>
    
    fun computation(val parameter1: Int, val parametre2: Double) : Int {
        //doing some computation
        return result
    }
}

class A {
    var property1 : Int 
    var property2 : Stirng 
    var property3 : B 
}

fun main (){
    val someValue = 0.4 //It's here to show the idea that the function `computation` needs also some other arguments that does not come from `A`'s propery
    val a = A()
    val result = a.property3.computation(a.property1,someValue)  // here is the line that bothers me !
}
```

Comment: I don't quite see the problem. Just encapsulate the logic in a method of `A` (`fun compute(val param: Double): Int { return property3.computation(property1, param); }`

Comment: [Also, relevant design principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: @crizzis I think you identified the problem, and you provided the solution. Basically, if you have code that accesses members of a property of another object, it may be a smell.

Comment: @Tenfour04 what do you mean by smell ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: @Tenfour04 if it is a smell, does this mean that I need to look further than the encapsulation suggested above?

Comment: The other person already commented how to fix it. I'm saying the smell (which you already identified as a problem in your question) is that code that is outside A has to know about `property3` and the functions of B. The other comment is a good solution to that design issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Builder design pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) to remove `computation` function from `B` class like this:

```kotlin
class B {
    val properties : MutableMap<String,Int> = HashMap()

    fun setProperty(name: String, value: Int) {
        this.properties[name] = value
    }
}

class A {
    var property1 : Int = 0
    var property2 : String = ""
    var property3 : B = B()
}

class Calculator(builder: Builder) {
    private val property1 = builder.property1
    private val someValue = builder.someValue
    private val properties = builder.properties

    companion object {
        fun builder() = Builder()
    }

    fun computation() : Int {
        //doing some computation
        val result = property1 + someValue.toInt() + properties.getOrDefault("value", 0)
        return result
    }

    class Builder {
        var property1: Int = 0
        var someValue: Double = 0.0;
        var properties : MutableMap<String,Int> = HashMap()

        fun property1(property1: Int): Builder {
            this.property1 = property1
            return this
        }

        fun someValue(someValue: Double): Builder {
            this.someValue = someValue
            return this
        }

        fun properties(properties : Map<String,Int>): Builder {
            this.properties.putAll(properties);
            return this
        }

        fun build(): Calculator {
            return Calculator(this)
        }
    }
}

fun main (){
    val someValue = 0.4 //It's here to show the idea that the function `computation` needs also some other arguments that does not come from `A`'s propery
    val a = A()
    a.property1 = 10
    a.property3.setProperty("value", 20)
    val result = Calculator.builder()
        .properties(a.property3.properties)
        .property1(a.property1)
        .someValue(someValue)
        .build()
        .computation()
    println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this?

```
fun main (){
    val someValue = 0.4
    val a = A()
    val result = with(a) {
        property3.computation(property1,someValue)
    } 
}
```